# Проблемы с установкой GTK+ на Windows

Tags: mingw, gtk

Использую Windows7 32, Возникла проблема с установкой GTK+ делаю все как сказано в мануале на офф сайте, проблема возникла уже на втором шаге. Установил MSYS2 и MinGW. MinGW устанавливаю не первый раз поэтому с ним все точно в порядке а вот с MSYS2 или самим GTK+ ничего не пойму.(кстати как я понял MSYS2 отдельно устанавливать не нужно он вроде идет вместе с MinGW) 
Проблема в том что при установке GTK+ командой `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3` в MSYS2 shell, все вроде устанавливается правильно но когда начинаю проверять видит ли команда pkg-config библиотеки и заголовочные файлы GTK то в ответ шелл мне пишет 
`$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
bash: pkg-config: команда не найдена`
В чем может быть проблема? 
P.S. В переменные среды добавил пути к MinGW, MSYS2 и GTK.

Comment: Установите утилиту  `pkg-config` в MSYS2. `pacman -S pkg-config`

Answer (score 1):

После долгих мучений с установкой и компиляцией GTK под MinGW составил небольшой мануал оставлю его в ответе может кому пригодится.

1. Install MinGW (with MSYS)
2. Download GTK  ("google: " gtk all-in-one bundle)
   "https://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-mingw/"
3. Add PATH to MinGW
   C:\MinGW\bin;
   C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\local\bin;
   C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin;
4. Copy all of folder with "gtk all-in-one bundle" to "C:\GTK"
5. Add PATH to GTK
   C:\GTK\bin;
6. Create "C" file (C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\Admin) [if "\home\username\"
   not exist, create them]
7. Open C:\MinGW\msys\1.0 msys.bat
8. gcc gtk.c -o gtk `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

Comment: Поддерживаю aio. Отделно ставить адово

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую установить **MSYS2** и делать так, как написано тут:

```
https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php
```

Я делал это для множества компов и систем. Проблем ни разу не возникло. Если все делать по приведенному ману, то **GTK+** устанавливается со всеми зависимостями, библиотеками и компилятором. Можно одновременно поставить **GTK+** как для **x64**, так и для **x86**.

Для того, чтобы сделать проект **GTK+** лично я использую самый последний **Code::Blocks.** Ставил его отдельно. Желательно ставить версию с компилятором.

Сам дефолтный компилятор **MinGW x32** нужен не будет, но вот его вкладка в настройках компилятора понадобиться для быстрого создания и настройки нового компилятора **MinGW**, который будет использоваться для сборки проектов **GTK+**.

Очень рекомендую использовать новый компилятор, который лежит в папке *msys/mingw32* или *msys/mingw64*, в зависимости от целевой платформы, под которую собираетесь компилировать. Это избавит от необходимости прописывать миллиарды путей и флагов для каждого проекта, так как все зависимости и файлы нового компилятора лежат рядом с файлами **GTK+**, включая **dll**, **lib**, **h** и множество других ресурсов.

Сперва вам необходимо добавить новый компилятор. Это проще всего сделать так:

- Скопировать вкладку стандартного компилятора, нажав **Copy**, обозвав новый компилятор, например **GTK+ 3 MinGW x64**;
- Перейти во вкладку **toolchain и** задать пути по аналогии с:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того, как вы добавите компилятор и укажите в **toolchain** пути к **exe**-шникам, вам необходимо создать новый проект **Console application**.

Для того, чтобы компилятор понял, что ваша консоль - это проект **GTK+** совсем не обязательно прописывать тонны путей в настройках проекта или в переменных окружения, достаточно лишь указать два флага.

**Compiler settings->Other compiler options:**

```
`pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags`
```

**Linker settings->Other linker options:**

```
`pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --libs`
```

Далее, если следующий код скомпилируется, все удалось:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```